как использовать end в функции input?
a = int(input('Введите значения A', end=' '))
b = a + 2
print(f'a){b}')

я только начала этим интересоваться, в книге с использованием end применяется только print, а я хочу чтоб после того как человек ввел значение A, значение не писалось на следующей строке. Можно же как то сделать. Мне выдает ошибку TypeError: input() takes no keyword arguments

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Вот документация: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input  Разве функция принимает несколько параметров?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1593337/562052

Функция input не принимает параметр end. Сделать так, чтобы значение не писалось на новой строке, нельзя.
На самом деле можно:
import sys
str = input()
sys.stdout.write("\033[F") # Удаление строки
print(str + "текст") # Возвращаем строку вместе с другим текстом


На Windows работать будет?

Если ввести нечто длинше чем string + "текст" то получается что-то вроде: ...текстgfg.

sys.stdout.write("\033[F") не стирает строку, а переносит курсор в начало строки.
